# The proper way to create a DirectX12 texture

Tags: c++, directx

I implemented a CPU path tracer that render to an image. That image is later blit on screen using DirectX 12.
The code has been working for years until i tried yesterday. **I suddently get artefacts**.
For example, here the floating point image generated by path tracing:
[image]

What i obtain after blitting on screen
[image]

In terms of code, here my base image class:

```
class Image
{
public:
    Image(const Image& src);
    virtual ~Image() {};

    nbUint32 getWidth() const;
    nbUint32 getHeight() const;
    nbUint64 getBytesPerRow() const;
    const unsigned char* getRawData() const;

    ImageFormat getFormat() const;
    nbUint32 getNbPixels() const;

protected:
    Image(ImageFormat imFormat);
    Image(nbUint32 width, nbUint32 height, ImageFormat imFormat);

    cv::Mat m_image;
    ImageFormat m_format;
};
```

Here is my renderer class that draw images on screen:

```
class DX12Renderer 
{
public:
    void drawImage(const Texture::Image& image) override;

    void createTexture2D(const Texture::Image* image, Dx12TextureHandle& dst);
    void releaseTexture(Dx12TextureHandle& textureHandle) const;

    //etc....
private:
    void createTexture2DArray(const std::vector<const Texture::Image*>& images,
        nbUint32 width, nbUint32 height, D3D12_SRV_DIMENSION viewDimension, Dx12TextureHandle& dst);

    void prepareViewportRender();

    enum class CommandType
    {
        Direct,
        Copy
    };

    struct CommandBuffer
    {
        ID3D12CommandAllocator* commandAllocator[SwapChainBufferCount];
        ID3D12GraphicsCommandList* commandList;
        ID3D12CommandQueue* commandQueue;
        ID3D12Fence* fences[SwapChainBufferCount];
        HANDLE fenceEvent;
        UINT64 fenceValue[SwapChainBufferCount];
        nbInt32 frameIndex;
    };

    std::unordered_map<CommandType, CommandBuffer> m_commandBuffers;

    Dx12TextureHandle m_blittingBuffers[SwapChainBufferCount];

    ID3D12Resource* m_renderTargets[SwapChainBufferCount];

    // Descriptor allocators
    std::unique_ptr<Descriptor::CBV_SRV_UAV_DescriptorAllocator> m_cbs_srv_uavAllocator;
    std::unique_ptr<Descriptor::RTV_DescriptorAllocator> m_rtvAllocator;
    std::unique_ptr<Descriptor::DSV_DescriptorAllocator> m_dsvAllocator;

    //etc....
}

inline void DX12Renderer::prepareViewportRender()
{
    auto& commandList = m_commandBuffers[CommandType::Direct].commandList;

    // Set the viewport
    commandList->RSSetViewports(1, &m_viewport);

    // Set the scissor rect
    commandList->RSSetScissorRects(1, &m_scissorRect);

    // Set the descriptor heaps
    ID3D12DescriptorHeap* descriptorHeaps[] = { m_cbs_srv_uavAllocator->getHeap() };
    commandList->SetDescriptorHeaps(_countof(descriptorHeaps), descriptorHeaps);
}

inline void DX12Renderer::drawImage(const Texture::Image& image)
{   
    prepareViewportRender();

    auto& commandList = m_commandBuffers[CommandType::Direct].commandList;
    const nbInt32 frameIdx = m_commandBuffers[CommandType::Direct].frameIndex;
    Dx12TextureHandle& blitBuffer = m_blittingBuffers[frameIdx];

    // TODO : Only recreate texture when image size is different.
    // Release current blit buffer
    if (blitBuffer.buffer)
        releaseTexture(blitBuffer);
    // Create texture from image
    createTexture2D(&image, blitBuffer);

    // Now draw
    commandList->ResourceBarrier(1, &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Transition(m_renderTargets[frameIdx], D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_PRESENT, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_RENDER_TARGET));

    CD3DX12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE rtvHandle(m_rtvDescriptorsHandle.getCpuHandle(),
        frameIdx,
        m_rtvAllocator->getDescriptorSize());

    commandList->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &rtvHandle, FALSE, nullptr);

    {
        Effect::RenderRectanglePushArgs args = { blitBuffer };
        m_renderRectangleEffect->pushDrawCommands(args, commandList, frameIdx);
    }

    commandList->ResourceBarrier(1, &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Transition(m_renderTargets[frameIdx], D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_RENDER_TARGET, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_PRESENT));
}

inline void DX12Renderer::createTexture2D(const Texture::Image* image, Dx12TextureHandle& dst)
{
    const nbUint32 width = image->getWidth();
    const nbUint32 height = image->getHeight();

    if (width > D3D12_REQ_TEXTURE2D_U_OR_V_DIMENSION)
        throw CreateTextureException("Image width is too high.");

    if (height > D3D12_REQ_TEXTURE2D_U_OR_V_DIMENSION)
        throw CreateTextureException("Image height is too high");

    createTexture2DArray({ image }, width, height, D3D12_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D, dst);
}

inline void DX12Renderer::createTexture2DArray(const std::vector<const Texture::Image*>& images,
    nbUint32 width, nbUint32 height, D3D12_SRV_DIMENSION viewDimension, Dx12TextureHandle& dst)
{
    const nbUint32 arraySize = (nbUint32)images.size();//arraySize is 1 for single textures.
    assert(arraySize < D3D12_REQ_TEXTURE2D_ARRAY_AXIS_DIMENSION);

    D3D12_RESOURCE_DESC textureDesc = {};
    textureDesc.Dimension = D3D12_RESOURCE_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    textureDesc.Alignment = 0; // may be 0, 4KB, 64KB, or 4MB. 0 will let runtime decide between 64KB and 4MB (4MB for multi-sampled textures)
    textureDesc.Width = width;
    textureDesc.Height = height;
    textureDesc.DepthOrArraySize = static_cast<std::uint16_t>(arraySize); // if 3d image, depth of 3d image. Otherwise an array of 1D or 2D textures.
    textureDesc.MipLevels = 1; // Number of mipmaps. We are not generating mipmaps for this texture, so we have only one level.

    const Texture::ImageFormat imageFormat = images[0]->getFormat();
    switch(imageFormat)
    {
    case Texture::ImageFormat::RGBA8:
        textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    break;

    case Texture::ImageFormat::RGB32F:
        textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT;
    break;

    case Texture::ImageFormat::RGBA32F:
        textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT;
    break;

    default:
        throw CreateTextureException("Unsupported image format");
   }

   textureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1; // This is the number of samples per pixel, we just want 1 sample
   textureDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0; // The quality level of the samples. Higher is better quality, but worse performance
   textureDesc.Layout = D3D12_TEXTURE_LAYOUT_UNKNOWN; // The arrangement of the pixels. Setting to unknown lets the driver choose the most efficient one
   textureDesc.Flags = D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_NONE; // no flags

   // Create the default heap.
   HRESULT hr = D3D12Device->CreateCommittedResource(
       &CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_DEFAULT),
       D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE,
       &textureDesc,
       D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_DEST, // We will copy the texture from the upload heap to here, so we start it out in a copy dest state
       nullptr,
       IID_PPV_ARGS(&dst.buffer));

   if (FAILED(hr))
   {
       return;
   }

   dst.format = textureDesc.Format;

   UINT64 textureUploadBufferSize;
   D3D12Device->GetCopyableFootprints(&textureDesc, 0, arraySize, 0, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, &textureUploadBufferSize);

   // Now we create an upload heap to upload our texture to the default heap
   ID3D12Resource* textureBufferUploadHeap;

   hr = D3D12Device->CreateCommittedResource(
       &CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_UPLOAD),
       D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE,
       &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC::Buffer(textureUploadBufferSize),
       D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_GENERIC_READ,
       nullptr,
       IID_PPV_ARGS(&textureBufferUploadHeap));

   if (FAILED(hr))
   {
        return;
   }


   // Initialize subresources
    std::vector<D3D12_SUBRESOURCE_DATA> subResourceData(arraySize);
    for (nbUint32 i = 0u; i < arraySize; ++i)
    {
        subResourceData[i].pData = images[i]->getRawData();
        subResourceData[i].RowPitch = images[i]->getBytesPerRow();
        subResourceData[i].SlicePitch = images[i]->getBytesPerRow() * height;
    }

    // Now we copy the upload buffer contents to the default heap            
   UpdateSubresources(m_commandBuffers[CommandType::Direct].commandList, dst.buffer, textureBufferUploadHeap, 0, 0, arraySize, &subResourceData[0]);

    m_commandBuffers[CommandType::Direct].commandList->ResourceBarrier(1, &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Transition(dst.buffer, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_DEST, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COMMON));

    // Create buffer view
    D3D12_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC srvDesc = {};
    srvDesc.Shader4ComponentMapping = D3D12_DEFAULT_SHADER_4_COMPONENT_MAPPING;
    srvDesc.ViewDimension = viewDimension;
    srvDesc.Format = dst.format;
    srvDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;
    dst.descriptorHandle = m_cbs_srv_uavAllocator->allocate({ dst.buffer }, srvDesc);
}

inline void releaseTexture(Dx12TextureHandle& textureHandle) const
{
    m_cbs_srv_uavAllocator->release(textureHandle.descriptorHandle);
    textureHandle.buffer->Release();
    textureHandle.buffer = nullptr;
}
```

Here the render rectangle effect:

```
void RenderRectangle::pushDrawCommands(RenderRectanglePushArgs& data, ID3D12GraphicsCommandList* commandList, nbInt32 frameIndex)
{    
    commandList->SetPipelineState(m_PSO);
    commandList->SetGraphicsRootSignature(m_rootSignature);
    commandList->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

    {
        PixelShaderCB cb;
        cb.color = { data.color.x, data.color.y, data.color.z, data.color.w };
        cb.hasTexture = !!data.textureHandle.buffer;
        memcpy(m_pixelShaderCBGPUAddress[frameIndex], &cb, sizeof(PixelShaderCB));
    }

    commandList->SetGraphicsRootConstantBufferView(0, m_pixelShaderCBUploadHeaps[frameIndex]->GetGPUVirtualAddress());

    if (data.textureHandle.buffer)
    {
        commandList->ResourceBarrier(1, &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Transition(data.textureHandle.buffer, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COMMON, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_PIXEL_SHADER_RESOURCE));
        commandList->SetGraphicsRootDescriptorTable(1, data.textureHandle.descriptorHandle.getGpuHandle());
    }

    commandList->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &m_vtxBuffer.bufferView);
    commandList->IASetIndexBuffer(&m_idxBuffer.bufferView);
    commandList->DrawIndexedInstanced(6, 1, 0, 0, 0);

    if (data.textureHandle.buffer)
    {
        commandList->ResourceBarrier(1, &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Transition(data.textureHandle.buffer, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_PIXEL_SHADER_RESOURCE, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COMMON));
    }
}
```

Here the render rectangle shaders:

```
/////////////////// VERTEX SHADER  ////////////////////
struct VS_INPUT
{
    float4 position : POSITION;
    float2 texCoord: TEXCOORD;
};

struct VS_OUTPUT
{
    float4 position: SV_POSITION;
    float2 texCoord: TEXCOORD;
};

VS_OUTPUT main(VS_INPUT input)
{
    VS_OUTPUT output;
    output.texCoord = input.texCoord;
    output.position = input.position;

    return output;
}

/////////////////// PIXEL SHADER  ////////////////////

struct VS_OUTPUT
{
    float4 position: SV_POSITION;
    float2 texCoord: TEXCOORD;
};

cbuffer PixelShaderCB : register(b0)
{
    float4 color;
    bool hasTexture;
};

Texture2D billboardTex : register(t0);
SamplerState tSampler : register(s0);

float4 main(VS_OUTPUT input) : SV_TARGET
{
    if (hasTexture)
        return billboardTex.Sample(tSampler, input.texCoord) * color;

    return color;
}
```

I checked on RenderDoc to validate the input texture is the issue.
I get this for inputs:

[image]

And this for outputs:
[image]

The input texture is clearly wrong. I believe it is due to the **createTexture2D** function, but i don't see why.
Also the output is surprisingly different from the input texture.

Comment: You need to post the code for `createTexture2D` for us to help. It looks like a problem with not respecting pitch alignment.

Comment: Thank a lot for helping :). The createTexture2D code  is present in my description. See the "Here is my renderer class that draw images on screen" section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue is only present on AMD devices.
Creation of my blitting textures with **DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT** format is somewhat wrong.
So I use a workaround, I convert the textures from **DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT** to **DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT** before blitting.
This works, the artefacts are gone.
Here the new drawImage function:

```
void DX12Renderer::drawImage(const Texture::Image& image)
{   
    prepareViewportRender();

    auto& commandList = m_commandBuffers[CommandType::Direct].commandList;
    const nbInt32 frameIdx = m_commandBuffers[CommandType::Direct].frameIndex;
    Dx12TextureHandle& blitBuffer = m_blittingBuffers[frameIdx];

    // TODO : Only recreate texture when image size is different.
    // Release current blit buffer
    if (blitBuffer.buffer)
        releaseTexture(blitBuffer);

    // Create texture from image.
    if (Hardware::HardwareInformationSingleton::instance()->isAmdGpu())
    {
        // Convert the RGB32F image to RGBA32F. Direct use of the RGB32F causes artefacts on AMD devices. 
        const Texture::SharedImagePtr rgba32FImage = Graphics::Texture::Helper::createRGBA32FFrom(*dynamic_cast<const Texture::RGB32FImage*>(&image));
        createTexture2D(rgba32FImage.get(), blitBuffer);
    }
    else
    {
        createTexture2D(&image, blitBuffer);
    }

    // Now draw
    commandList->ResourceBarrier(1, &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Transition(m_renderTargets[frameIdx], D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_PRESENT, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_RENDER_TARGET));

    CD3DX12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE rtvHandle(m_rtvDescriptorsHandle.getCpuHandle(),
    frameIdx,
    m_rtvAllocator->getDescriptorSize());

    commandList->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &rtvHandle, FALSE, nullptr);

    {
        Effect::RenderRectanglePushArgs args = { blitBuffer };
        m_renderRectangleEffect->pushDrawCommands(args, commandList, frameIdx);
    }

    commandList->ResourceBarrier(1, &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Transition(m_renderTargets[frameIdx], D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_RENDER_TARGET, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_PRESENT));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The bug here is that you are assuming the row pitch of the texture resource Is the same as your source image. That's not necessarily true. You need to copy row-by-row and advance the two pointers by their respective rowPitch:

- Advance the source pointer by `image->getBytesPerRow()`.
- Advance the destination pointer by `D3D12_SUBRESOURCE_INFO.RowPitch`.

See **MemcpySubresource** in the [D3DX12](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Headers/blob/main/include/directx/d3dx12_resource_helpers.h#L45) utility helper.

Comment: Isn't the UpdateSubresources function handling the different pitch? I looked at the implementation and it end up using MemcpySubresource.

Comment: I do almost the same thing than the MiniEngine texture allocator. I dont see where i'm wrong:
https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/blob/master/MiniEngine/Core/Texture.cpp
  
See: void Texture::Create2D( size_t RowPitchBytes, size_t Width, size_t Height, DXGI_FORMAT Format, const void* InitialData )